# NAudio: is it possible to record in MP3 or AAC without using the filesystem?

Tags: naudio

I'm using NAudio for a project that needs to record voice using the microphone. The NAudio project has a very nice demo that shows how to record a wav file, but since I need to transfer the voice-data to a server using webservices, a wav file is often too large.

Therefore I was wondering if it possible to do the same in MP3 or AAC directly. In [this article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.nl/2015/02/how-to-encode-mp3s-with-naudio.html) I read that it is not possible to encode to any other format using (memory) streams and that file paths are required. I cannot assume that my client application has access to the file system.

Is there any way to create or encode an MP3 file directly without using the filesystem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid NAudio doesn't currently support doing that, but one technique that you could try is to use Lame.exe and pipe PCM into stdin and read the MP3 converted output from stdout.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! For now I will use a FileStream for the encoding. If this becomes a problem in the future then I will try your solution.